# Retrieve data from a table using a list of Ids extracted from another table using the Unit of Work Pattern in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, repository, unit-of-work

The Purpose is to retrieve a list of all employees from the Technician's table. And than using that list of IDs, a search has to be performed on the Reviews Table thereby generating a list of all the Reviews by those employees.

I have used the Unit of Work and Repository Pattern for Data Access.

```
   tech = unitOfWork.TechnicianRepository.GetAll().Where(b=>b.Branch =="Calgary").AsEnumerable().Select(r => new Review{TechnicianID =r.UserId, }).ToList();
```

Than before sending this to the view I cast it within the controller

```
      public IActionResult Index()
      {

        var result = ((IEnumerable)tech).Cast<Review>().ToList();
        return View(result);
      }
```

The following is for one of the returned results.

```
  [{"id":0,"technicianID":"c62a2746-1bfc-484f-a479-084e0be389a4","overAllTechRating":0,"origin":null,"name":null,"feedbackText":null,"date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}
```

So as can be seen here, the user ID is being extracted from the Technicians table, however all the other fields are appearing null for those Ids.

Here are the updates of what I have tried so far since I posted the question:

Tried METHOD:-

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

         var result = unitOfWork.TechnicianRepository.GetAll().Where(b => b.Branch == "Calgary").AsEnumerable().Select(r=> new {r.UserId});

        List<Review> array = new List<Review>();
        while (result != null) {

            array.Add(unitOfWork.ReviewRepository.GetByGuidId(result.First().UserId));
        }
        return View(array);
    }
```

And after trying this one, I was able to get my UserID pass to the UnitOfWork GetByGuidId() function, however, it fails to find the object, return a bad request.

Here is how it looks like :

```
    public virtual T GetByGuidId(Guid? Id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(Id);
    }
```

Comment: The probably what you want is `IEnumerable<Guid> Ids = unitOfWork.TechnicianRepository.GetAll().Where(b => b.Branch =="Calgary").Select(x => x.UserId);` to first get the ID values. Then `IEnumerable<Review> reviews = yourRepository.Reviews.Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.UserId);` but its impossible to be sure without your models and knowing what is the relationship between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason could be that the Technician object was not instantiated, so the data store never returned the object. It returned the Technician Id because it was a foreign key in the same table.